# RavenDB Query on Inner property serialize with [JsonProperty]

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am having trouble querying from RavenDB with `[JsonProperty]`.

The following test doesn't work.

(Note: I am aware that I have use use the new namespace `Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json`):

```
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Raven.Client.Embedded;
using Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace RavenTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class RavenFixture
    {
        protected EmbeddableDocumentStore DocumentStore;

        [SetUp]
        public void BaseSetUp()
        {
            DocumentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true };
            DocumentStore.Initialize();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(new Parent {Inner = new Child {Num = 1}});
                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                var list = session.Query<Parent>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
                       .Where(x => x.Inner.Num == 1)
                       .ToList();

                Assert.That(list.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
            }
        }

        public class Parent
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }

            //If you comment this out, it will work
            [JsonProperty("N")]
            public Child Inner { get; set; }
        }

        public class Child
        {
            [JsonProperty("M")]
            public int Num { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I comment out the line `[JsonProperty("N")]`, it works as expected.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I am using RavenDB 2.5.0.0 (latest)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the query provider for DocumentSession.Query<> where it will not honor the Newtonsoft attributes on documents.

However if you use the Lucene query provider it will perform as expected:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(new Parent {Inner = new Child {Num = 1}});
            session.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var list = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Parent>()
                   .WhereEquals(x => x.Inner.Num, 1)
                   .ToList();

            Assert.That(list.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, unfortunately that didn't work for me. Which version of RavenDB are you using? Strangely, using LuceneQuery results in the same behavior. It works if I comment out `[JsonProperty("N")]`.

Comment: I tested it on build 2375.

Comment: I tested on build 2622 and 2601 and it doesn't work. I am pretty sure this is a bug and is looking forward for a fix in the future.